# Convert C realloc to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, memory, realloc

```
int StackRealloc(stack* S){

  if ((S->array = realloc(S->array,sizeof(int)*(S->size)*2)) != NULL){
    S->size = (S->size)*2;
    return 1;
  }
  else return 0;
}
```

How Can I Convert This Code( c ) to Delphi ( Delphi7 ) ?

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with? You've read the documentation for C's `realloc`, right? And you've compared it with the Delphi memory-management functions you're using in the rest of your program, right? What's left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Delphi function that is analagous to C `realloc` is [`ReallocMem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ReallocMem).

You could, if you wished, make a literal translation of the C struct into a Delphi record, and then call `ReallocMem`. But in Delphi you would most likely use a dynamic array instead of raw pointers:

```
var
  arr: array of Integer;
...
SetLength(arr, Length(arr)*2);
```

There's no need for a struct that contains both array and size because a Delphi dynamic array keeps track of its own length.

What's more you would not signal errors using `0` or `1` as your return value. Instead you would not write any explicit error checking in your code and let the runtime raise an exception should the call to `SetLength` fail.

Since you appear to be implementing a stack, you could use the `TStack` class found in the `Contnrs` unit. In modern Delphi you could use `Generics.Collections.TStack<Integer>` instead.

As an aside, the C code is broken. It fails to handle errors correctly. If the call to `realloc` fails, then `NULL` is returned. Since you store that away to `S->array`, then you lost track of the original block of memory and will therefore leak it. One of the golden rules of C programming is that you never write: `p = realloc(p, ...)`.